# Is a suggestion to use a tool instead of telling the OP how to accomplish the task really an answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48394030/4639281) using the Not an Answer flag, because it is a remark about using a package manager, which has nothing to do with the question asked.

The post was reviewed with an outcome of 3 Looks OK and 3 Recommend Deletion.

Does this post qualify as an answer?

Comment: It looks like an attempt to answer the question using a package manager. Therefore it's not NAA. [Read the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/215552).

Comment: Does that really attempt to answer? It reads more like a rant to me.

Comment: The line of code, `sudo apt-get install imagick-php5` appears to my eyes to install the package the question is asking about. Remember, NAA is only for things that a person not versed in the technology could not possibly see as an answer.

Comment: I know when to flag as NAA. That's _why_ I did. I don't see it as an attempt to answer, but rather a rant.

Comment: An answer can be both an attempt and a rant. Although both circumstances may attract downvotes, I don't think it merits a NAA flag.

Comment: Why not just edit it?

Answer (score 7):

Hmmmmmm... yes, it's an answer. And actually the only sensible answer. People should stop messing with compiling php and packages by themselves when they obviously do not know how to synchronize everything.

That deserves upvotes, not criticism.

Comment: +1 an answer saying "Don't do <horrible thing>, use the tool that was designed to accomplish the task instead" is not only an answer, but often times it is the best answer. (unless it recommends the use of jQuery, in which case the offender should be hell-banned)